# SpringBoot - selective configuration loading (or excluding)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have SpringBoot application and I would like to ask for help in implementing such a scenario:

I have two integration tests . I would like the first of them to run with the MongoDB support and the other without it. I have prepared two set of classes:

```
      runs                       loads
TestA ---> TestAApplication ---> TestAConfiguration
```

```
     runs                  loads
TestB ---> TestBApplication ---> TestBConfiguration
```

TestBConfiguration disables all MongoDB support.

Both configurations register the same bean - SomeBean.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestAApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestA {
    @Test
    public void runTest(){
    System.out.println("Test with active MongoDB support");
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
class TestAApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestAApplication.class)
              .sources(new Class<?>[]{
                      TestAConfiguration.class
              })
              .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET).run(args);
  }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class TestAConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        return new SomeBean() ;
    }

}
```

TestB code is very similar the main difference is in the class TestBConfiguration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
        , MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
        , EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class})
class TestBConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
     return new SomeBean() ;
     }

}
```

When I run TestA I get an error

```
The bean 'someBean', defined in class path resource [mw/experimental/TestBConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [mw/experimental/TestAConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

Why TestA is loading TestB configuration ?

I was convinced that such code:

```
 new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestAApplication.class)
              .sources(new Class<?>[]{
                      TestAConfiguration.class
              })
              .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET).run(args);
```

causes the context to be loaded only with the one configuration indicated (TestAConfiguration in this example).

Unfortunately both configurations are loaded and the context is not initialized correctly.

Is it possible to indicate the configuration to be loaded (or exclude the one I do not want) ?

Comment: because they are annotated `@Configuration` and get found and registered automatically during startup. Don't user `sources` read the documentation, there is an entire section about how to load in custom configuration during tests. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config

Comment: Thank you very much, this section in documentation has explained a lot to me...